# Can I have access to the call stack in my code?

Tags: c++, call

Let's say I have a function:

```
firstFunction(){
    //some code here
    secondFunction();//call secondFunction
}
```

And inside `secondFunction()`

```
secondFunction(){
    //some code here
    //here call the function that called this ( in this case firstFunction() )
}
```

I want to call whatever function called another function within that *next-in-the-call-stack* function without having to explicitly write the function's name. Is that possible?

Comment: There's no portable way to do this.  Is your question academic, or do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: How would you know which arguments to pass to the function? How would the compiler know how many bytes comprise the returned value (needed even if the returned value is discarded)? This approach seems to be a significant breach of encapsulation. Depending on what your underlying goal is, there is probably a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not explicitly provide this feature. There are some libraries you can use to print a backtrace, but if functions are inlined, they could be elided from the list.

You'll probably need to track this yourself with some function argument.